# How to create a list with following format?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Can any one help me how to create the list with the following format, I don't need the symbol, but i need the count at right corner and text at left corner.

Code:

```
  <ul data-role="listview" id="locationList">
     <li>premo1 60</li>
     <li>premo2 100</li>
     <li>premo3 150</a></li>                            
    </ul>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `float` property to set your elements in left and right like this:

CSS:

```
.left {float:left;}
.right {float:right;}
```

HTML:

```
<li>
    <div class="left">premo1</div>
    <div class="right">60</div>
</li>
```

Comment: whats not coming? check this http://jsfiddle.net/3eC3w/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3eC3w/2/ - I just added constraint to the width of the ul to make it look slightly better. Example is correct otherwise.

Comment: I didn't down voted for you. I accepted your answer

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery Mobile, there are classes built in for displaying a count on the right (ui-li-count):

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-count-theme="a" data-inset="false">
    <li><p>Inbox <span class="ui-li-count">12</span></p></li>
    <li><p>Outbox <span class="ui-li-count">0</span></p></li>
    <li><p>Drafts <span class="ui-li-count">4</span></p></li>
    <li><p>Sent <span class="ui-li-count">328</span></p></li>
    <li><p>Trash <span class="ui-li-count">62</span></p></li>
</ul>
```

If you want to get rid of the border around the count, add this CSS:

```
.ui-li-count {
    border: 0;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Fr7u3/)**

Comment: easy one, welcome back ;)

Comment: @Omar, thanks i think my mind is still on vacation :)

Answer (score 0):

No need to use un-necessary uses of `float` property in this case. As appear in picture the layout can be achieve just using `float:right` . Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/coconude/5/edit)**.

**CSS Code**

```
ul#locationList{padding:0 margin:0; overflow:hidden;}

ul#locationList li{ list-style-type:none; border-top:1px solid gray; padding:10px;}

ul#locationList li:last-child{ list-style-type:none; border-bottom:5px solid gray; padding:10px;

}

ul#locationList li a
{float:right;display:inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
}

ul#locationList li a:after
{
 content: "\f004"; 
 font-family: FontAwesome;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ef8913;
 font-size: 15px;
 margin:0 10px;
}
```